# Upload file in ASP.NET MVC (Again!)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, upload, httppostedfile

I have a problem with uploading file in asp.net mvc 2.
My controller function's parameter is a `FormCollection` type. Because the fields are too numerous, I can't separate each field as a parameter. I have 2 upload file fields in my form. How can I get uploaded files in my controller?

I tried this way:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgent(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase personImage)
{
    ...
}
```

but `personImage` was `null`. :(

or this way:

`HttpPostedFileBase img = this.HttpContext.Request.Files[collection["personImage"]];`

but `img` was `null` to. Also `collection["personImage"]` was the name of selected file (without path) and I can't cast it to `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Note that all fields must be filled in on one page. I can't let the customer upload images in a separate page!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by reading [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx). Then apply it to your scenario:

```
<form action="/Home/CreateAgent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file" />

    ... Some other input fields for which we don't care at the moment
        and for which you definetely should create a view model
        instead of using FormCollection in your controller action

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

which translated in WebForms language gives:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgent", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file" />

    ... Some other input fields for which we don't care at the moment
        and for which you definetely should create a view model
        instead of using FormCollection in your controller action

    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult CreateAgent(
    // TODO: To be replaced by a strongly typed view model as the 
    // ugliness of FormCollection is indescribable
    FormCollection collection, 
    HttpPostedFileBase file1, 
    HttpPostedFileBase file2
)
{
    // use file1 and file2 here which are the names of the corresponding
    // form input fields
}
```

If you have many files then use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` as illustrated by Haacked.

Remarks:

- Absolutely never use `this.HttpContext.Request.Files` in an ASP.NET MVC application
- Absolutely never never never use `this.HttpContext.Request.Files[collection["personImage"]]` in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Do you mean that we never should use `this.HttpContext.Request` ?

Comment: @Jalal Amini, you should not use `this.HttpContext.Request.Files`. By the way thanks to the default model binder you might even avoid the usage of `this.HttpContext.Request`.

Answer (score 2):

What does your using statement look like in your view for the form? It should look something like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgent", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Comment: Yes: `<% using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgent", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))%>`

Comment: @Jalai Amini Does the name of your file input match the parameter on the CreateAgent signature?